# I can't have two monitors at the same time on Ubuntu 17.10 using Xorg

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display

I have a laptop (HP 6730b) with an external monitor. It worked fine on Ubuntu 12.04. But on Ubuntu 17.10 both monitors are black with flickering if I try to startup using Xorg. It works with either monitor but not both at once.

It does work with both at the same time using Wayland. But Wayland is very unstable for me and the computer freezes frequently after a while with the hdd working a lot. Mostly with Firefox or Atom which is quite heavy applications. Most of the time I can't even switch to text console ctrl-alt-F5.

Any way I can have it working with both monitors at the same time using Xorg as before?!

$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1200, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1680x1050     60.01 +  59.95    59.88
   1600x1024     60.17
   1400x1050     59.98
   1280x1024     60.02
   1440x900      59.89
   1280x960      60.00
   1360x768      59.80    59.96
   1152x864      60.00
   1024x768      60.04    60.00
   960x720       60.00
   928x696       60.05
   896x672       60.01
   960x600       60.00
   960x540       59.99
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25
   840x525       60.01    59.88
   800x512       60.17
   700x525       59.98
   640x512       60.02
   720x450       59.89
   640x480       60.00    59.94
   680x384       59.80    59.96
   576x432       60.06
   512x384       60.00
   400x300       60.32    56.34
   320x240       60.05
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1600x1200     60.00
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1152x864      75.00
   1024x768      75.03    60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32
   640x480       75.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
SVIDEO-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)